# Notepad++ highlighted code into LaTeX?

Tags: highlighting

I want to export my Notepad++ highlighted code into LaTeX. Is it possible?

Note that my codes are PHP codes.

Comment: Do you mean having your code in the LaTeX output file (`.pdf` for example) highlighted as you can see it in your editor?

Comment: yes, almost certainly- the `listings` or `minted` packages will be your friend here

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.SX!](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436)

Comment: @karlkoeller, I have this http://i.imgur.com/mGdEj9e.png and I can make this http://i.imgur.com/Gi5o3gf.png using Plugins->NppExport->Copy HTML to Clipboard, then pasting it to Word. But I don't know how to make it into TEX.

Answer (score 4):

Consider using `lstset` from the `listings` package.  Note that any option you don't want globally (or technically, global to the current group) can be set as part of the optional argument to `\begin{lstlisting}`.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{xcolor} % for more colors

\usepackage{listings}
\lstset{
        basicstyle=\small\ttfamily,
       stringstyle=\color{black!40!white}\ttfamily,
      keywordstyle=\color{blue},
      commentstyle=\color{green!50!black},
  showstringspaces=false,
   backgroundcolor=\color{black!5!white}
}


\usepackage{framed} % for contrast
\begin{document}
% Example source from http://php.net/manual/en/function.readdir.php
\begin{framed}
\begin{lstlisting}[language=php]
<?php

if ($handle = opendir('/path/to/files')) {
    echo "Directory handle: $handle\n";
    echo "Entries:\n";

    /* This is the correct way to
       loop over the directory. */
    while (false !== ($entry = readdir($handle))) {
        echo "$entry\n";
    }

    /* This is the WRONG way to
       loop over the directory. */
    while ($entry = readdir($handle)) {
        echo "$entry\n";
    }

    closedir($handle);
}
?>
\end{lstlisting}
\end{framed}
\end{document}
```

[image: output]